Invalid JNDI name in Wildfly 27
As a part of application migration from jdk8 to jdk 17, I have migrated our web application from javax ee to Jakarta EE 10.
The EAR was deployed successfully in the server, but  getting invalid JNDI name when trying to access the application.
I have set the JNDI name for the bean  in the below format :
java:global/<EAR name>/Bean class
The Context class and InitialContext classes are still from javax.naming package.
Is there change for the Context class in jdk17/jakarta 10?
Unable to figure out what is causing the "Invalid JNDI name" issue. PLease help.
